# JIRA. Несколько фильтров в одном

Tags: jira

Доброго времени суток , Скажите пожалуйста , мне для работы , необходимо делать в Jira много фильтров , на подобии таких : Кол-во багов до , Кол-во багов после , Найдено во время и т.д. - скажите , есть ли какой-нибудь способ объединить все эти запросы в один фильтр - что бы он выводил как бы сразу 3 фильтра ?

Answer (score 1):

сохрани каждый фильтр отдельно. а потом filter in (idfilter1,idfilter2) - и так объединяй и сочетай любое количество

Answer (score 0):

Откройте редактор фильтра и составьте запрос с несколькими запросами фильтров, разделенными `and`, например:

```
assignee = currentUser() and reporter != currentUser()
and (status = Open or status = "In Progress" or status = Reopened) 
ORDER BY updated ASC
```

Тот запрос выводит джиры, созданные на пользователя и не показывает те, что пользователь создавал на самого себя и оставляет джиры только с статусом `Open`/`In Progress`/`Reopened`, сортируя их по дате последнего обновления.

Редактор выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это немного не то . В этом случае выводит не разные а делает выборку по заданным параметрам . Мне бы хотелось все же взять мои фильтры , вставить их в одну строку и получить на одной странице ответ состоящий из моих фильтров , при этом под каждым , хотелось бы видеть количество задач/багов